# Vectorize an iterative process

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I've written the following code in python; it takes an image and basically converts it from polar to cartesian coordinates; the effect is the image is 'unfurled' about a point.

```
def unravel(img, origin):
  max_radius =  min(origin)

  out = np.zeros((max_radius,720,3), np.uint8)

  for phi in range(0,720):
    for r in range(0, max_radius):
      target = cmath.rect(r,math.radians(phi/2))
      out[(r,phi)] = img[(max_radius + target.real, max_radius+target.imag)]
  return out
```

This algorithm is real slow; I really need this to operate on live video. Ideally i'd like to be able to 'matrixize' this so that the underlying calculation is performed with C rather than Python loops. I'm not particularly experienced doing this; what's the best approach?

Comment: This might be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations#To_Cartesian_coordinates_from_polar_coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach is to create a proper set of indexes beforehand and use Numpy's image magic for conversion:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.random.rand(140,100) # my sample image 

img_n,img_m = img.shape  # dimensions of image
p_n, p_m = int(np.ceil(np.linalg.norm(img.shape))), 360*2 # dimensions for out array
cc = [img_n/2, img_m/2] # origin for polar coordinates

# Generate sets of indexes of the polar array (do this only once):
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(img_m), np.arange(img_n))
Z = (X - cc[0]) + 1j*(Y-cc[1]) # create complex array of image coordinates
r,phi = np.abs(Z), np.angle(Z) + np.pi
rc = np.array(np.rint(r), dtype=int) # radial indexes
phic = np.array(np.rint(phi*(p_m-1)/(2*np.pi)), dtype=int) # angular indexes

# Do the the conversion:
out = np.zeros((p_n, p_m))
out[rc, phic] = img  # utilize numpy's index magic
```

To do such things to a video seems uncommon to me. In case you want to do something like feature extraction, please note that there also other techniques such as a [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

Answer (score 1):

This is a little high level, but you're going to have to get your hands dirty if you want to be able to stream video with a matrix transformation. This is not something you can reasonably do with your current approach.

Possibly the most accessible approach is to use [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) with a custom plugin. There are [python bindings](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gst_1.0/index.html) and some [useful tutorials](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/) for getting started with pipe-lining. You probably want to borrow heavily from the [geometrictransform](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-plugin-geometrictransform.html) plugins (or they might already do what you want).

You could also try expanding your question and adding tags for gstreamer, etc.